# Fermion self-energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, fermions, self-energy

I try to calculate the mass matrix for a massless fermion mediated by a loop of massless (right handed) neutrino and a scalar like the next diagram

[image]

The amplitude is given by:

$$  i M = \bar{u}_{s_i}(p) [i\Sigma_{ij}(k)] u_{s_j}(p), $$ The mass matrix:

$$ i\Sigma_{ij}(k) =
- \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}~ y_{im}~ P_R ~\frac {p\!\!\!/+k\!\!\!/}{(p+k)^2+i\epsilon}~ P_l  \frac{y_{jm}}{(k)^2-m_x^2+i\epsilon} $$

After Feynman parametrization, the integral is divergent at d=4, and I used the Pauli-Villars regularization as in Peskin's book Equ. (7.18), 
that ended up to

$$ \Sigma_{ij}(k) = \frac{  y_{jm} y_{im} \Gamma(2)^{-1}}{(16\pi^2)}
   P_R^2 ~ p\!\!\!/ \int^1_0~ dx~ (1-x) ~ \log\Big( \frac{x\mu^2}{(1-x)m^2-xp^2} \Big) \\
= \frac{ y_{jm} y_{im} }{(32\pi^2)}~ P_R^2 ~ p\!\!\!/ ~ (-1+\log\frac{\mu^2}{m^2}) $$

Does this calculation look right? Also to determine $\Sigma$, I have two problems , what will be the value of $p\!\!\!/$ ? In Peskin it had a similar formula Equ. (7.19) when calculating the electron self energy, then he set $p\!\!\!/ = m_0$ the mass of the electron according to a scheme indeed I didn't understand now too much, but for my case the external and the propagating fermions are massless, so how $p\!\!\!/$ can be evaluated ?

Second, it's apparent that $\Sigma$ is ultraviolet divergent, so what could be the value of $\mu$ (the renormalization scale) , I mean what could be the cut- off scale ?